# bootstrap tour no working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

bootstrap tour no working

[**Jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9LcQx/)

```html
<pre>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="bootstrap-tour.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
  <br/>
    <div class="container">
<button class="btn" id="tour-go">Start the tour!</button>
<br/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">

<div class="panel panel-default" id="my-element">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content 1
  </div>
</div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">

<div class="panel panel-default" id="my-other-element">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title 2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content 2
  </div>
</div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title 3</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content 3
  </div>
</div>

  </div>
</div>

    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-tour.js"></script>
    <script>

// Instance the tour
var tour = new Tour({
  steps: [
  {
    element: "#my-element",
    title: "Title of my step",
    content: "Content of my step"
  },
  {
    element: "#my-other-element",
    title: "Title of my step",
    content: "Content of my step"
  }
]});

// Initialize the tour
tour.init();


$('#tour-go').click(function () {
    // Start the tour
    tour.start();
});

    </script>
  </body>
</html>

</pre>
```

Comment: Any errors in console/

Comment: its working on jsfiddle, whats the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use, it is a cookie based tour, to start it forcefully pass `true` in `.start()`

```
tour.start(true) // Pass true to force the start.
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9LcQx/88/)